# Use Partial class (.dbml)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm working in a .NET with linq, and I have some behaviour that could be placed inside the class defined in the dbml (like a .`Load()` method) or outside in a new class that wraps around the dbml class.

This scenario repeats itself quite a few times in the application and I wanted to know if there's a best practice for this kind of situation.

Example

```
//Adds methods to the Contact class created in the dbml
public partial class Contact 
{
    public Contact Load(int Id) 
    {
       //Select and return a loaded Contact Object
    }
}

//or

public class ContactWrapper 
{
    public Contact Load(int Id) 
    {
       //Select and return a loaded Contact Object
    }
}

//or some other way that I didn't realize
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create another class part, just like you have in your example. This is a common pattern for extending generated classes.